# After Test Case/Suite/Plan Migration all Test Cases appear as "Active" - does not match source state

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

After performing a migration for a Team Area (Work Items then Test configs) the feedback I have from my tester colleague is that every Test that has migrated is sitting in an "Active" state, when a good number of these have either "Passed", "Failed" or "In Progress" on the source platform.

Is this a limitation of the WorkItemMigrationConfig or of any of the Test configuration processors? is this expected behaviour?

It is quite pertinent to retain the outcome states of Tests that have been run historically

Comment: To be clear, when our Tester mentioned the "State", I think she meant "Outcome". So all Outcomes of Test Cases in the Test Plan view are 'Active'. Is this a limitation of migrating Test Results data?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour.

There is no way to migrate Test Runs (which is where that data comes from) to another environment. Test results data is lost during a migration.